# Android Force class to be of a minimal type

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a class in witch i need to return a Active inherited class.

I now have done it like this

```
public Class GetActivityClass() {
    return baseSwitchActivity.class;
}
```

But in a inherited class I can return what ever class. But I want to force it is a class that extends `Activity`. Is there a syntax which I can use something like

```
public Class<T extends Activity> GetActivityClass() {
    return baseSwitchActivity.class;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. What you're looking for is a [bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
public Class<? extends Activity> GetActivityClass() {
    return baseSwitchActivity.class;
}
```